# Can't ping server 2k3 machine from win7 machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, dd-wrt

For some reason I can't connect to or ping a server 2k3 (enterprise) machine I just setup from my windows 7 machine.

I use DD-wrt with a wrt54g v4 router, and I've assigned them both static leases so they receive their same respective IPs constantly.

I can ping the w7 from the 2k3, but not the other way around - The router does show it assigned the lease and the connection is active for both machines though.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check your Windows Server firewall settings. You may have disabled the ping response.

Comment: It's a stock install, unless that's a default setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to click 'finish' on the initial setup wizard - I closed it with alt+f4 and manually configured windows update; when I restarted the computer and clicked finish it gave me a message saying 'Oh by the way now inbound traffic will be allowed, k?'...

That was nice of Windows to protect me, I suppose. Heh.

Comment: Well that's good to know. Please accept your answer so that it can be closed.